# value type error Python3: can only concatenate tuple

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I am creating a small program that looks if the License is valid (this part works), and increment 1 to "used" (a column that supports "int") each time the License in question is used. (Column supports "int") each time the License in question is used (Here I have an error and I don't really see how to solve it: "can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple"

The code:

```py
def check_database_license(license):
  mycursor = mydb.cursor()
  mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM license")
  result = mycursor.fetchall()
  for elements in result:
    if license in elements:
      temp = elements
      update_used_value(elements[2])
      return True
  return False

def update_used_value(id):
  mycursor = mydb.cursor()
  mycursor.execute("SELECT used FROM license WHERE id = {}".format(id))
  result = mycursor.fetchall()

  oldvalue = result[0]
  sql = "UPDATE customers SET address = %s WHERE address = %s"
  newvalue = oldvalue + 1
  val = (newvalue, oldvalue)

  mycursor.execute(sql, val)
  mydb.commit()
```

[phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp1rw.png)

Comment: You can replace `val = (newvalue, oldvalue)` with `val = [[newvalue], [oldvalue]]` in order to have a list to be used within `mycusor.execute` statement.

Comment: Hello, same problem

Comment: get rid of quotes you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

```
newvalue = oldvalue[0] + 1
```

replace newvalue in code and it should work